# SQL Query - Replacing a period in field name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

So, I have a form that uses Ajax/Jquery to POST an array over to this PHP file, which should be writing the array to the MySQL database. I have looked at several examples over the past two weeks and refined the code structure, but I feel I may be missing something obvious. Either that, or doing something really inefficiently. As background on the other files, the form itself has some input names that have a period in them, which is why there is a preg_replace in there. The variables.php file contains all correct SQL login data, as the back-end viewing of the data is working. All that is not working is the actual writing of the data.

However, if this code segment looks like it should work, then I need to check through my Javascript file again.

Here is the PHP Code:

```
include 'variables.php';

if (isset($_POST)){
    mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);
    mysqli_select_db($con,$mysql_table);
    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO '.$mysql_table.' (%s) VALUES ("%s")',
    implode(',',array_keys(preg_replace("/[^,.]/",$_fields))),
    implode('","',array_values(preg_replace("/[^,.]/",$_fields)))
    );
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    mysqli_close($con);
};
```

Here is the Javascript code that captures the form data:

```
var orderSubTotal ='46.15';
var orderTotal  ='46.15';
var numOfItems ='2';
var items =new Array('item1','item2');
var ids =new Array('id1','id2');
var codes =new Array('code1','code2');
var qtys =new Array('1','1');
var price =new Array('44.95','1.2');
var orderTax ='0';
var orderShipping ='0';
var appliedPromoIdList ='';
var coupon ='';
var storeId ='storeid';
var activeShipPromotionCount ='';
var itemImages  =new Array('image1','image2');

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#driver").click(function(event) {
    event.PreventDefault();

    var date=new Date();
    var formData = $("#testform :input[id!='card-type'][id!='paymentSelection_0']"+
    "[id!='ccSelectedRadio'][id!='card-number'][id!='card-exp-month'][id!='card-exp-year'][id!='card-cvv'][id!='billing-first-name']"+
    "[id!='billing-last-name'][id!='billing-company'][id!='billing-address1'][id!='billing-address2'][id!='billing-city']"+
    "[id!='billing-state'][id!='billing-zip'][id!='billing-phone'][id!='billing-country'][id!='useShippingRadio'][id!='useBillingRadio']"+
    "[id!='ppSelectedRadio'][name!='miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_ymixval'][name!='miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_ymixlabel']"+
    "[name!='miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_secname'][name!='paymentSelectionDS.paymentSelection_ROW0_paymentPPSelected']").serializeArray();

    formData.push({name: 'Subtotal', value: orderSubTotal});
    formData.push({name: 'Total', value: orderTotal});
    formData.push({name: 'Cart Size', value: numOfItems});
    formData.push({name: 'Cart Contains', value: items});
    formData.push({name: 'Item ID\'s', value: ids});
    formData.push({name: 'Codes', value: codes});
    formData.push({name: 'Quantities', value: qtys});
    formData.push({name: 'Prices', value: price});
    formData.push({name: 'Taxable', value: orderTax});
    formData.push({name: 'Shipping', value: orderShipping});
    formData.push({name: 'Applied Promotion ID\'s', value: appliedPromoIdList});
    formData.push({name: 'Coupons', value: coupon});
    formData.push({name: 'Store ID', value: storeId});
    formData.push({name: 'Shipping Promotion\'s', value: activeShipPromotionCount});
    formData.push({name: 'Item Images', value: itemImages});
    formData.push({name: 'Date and Time', value: date});

    $.post("jquery/process.php", formData);
});
});
```

Lastly, here is the form itself(I have removed sections of the form that are either excluded by the ajax post or don't even get pulled at all):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>the title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stage1" style="background-color:blue;">
        STAGE - 1
    </div>
    <form id="testform">
        <div id="ys_buyerInfo" class="">
            <div id="ys_shipBillShippingInfo" class="ys_majorSection">
                <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
                <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
                <div class="ys_subSection" id="ys_shippingAddress" style="">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="shipping-first-name" id="labelshipping-first-name" class="text"> <strong>First Name:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_first_name" id="shipping-first-name" size="31" maxlength="99" value="" />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-last-name" id="labelshipping-last-name" class="text"> <strong>Last Name:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_last_name" id="shipping-last-name" size="31" maxlength="99" value="" />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-company" id="labelshipping-company" class="text"> <strong>Company:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_company" id="shipping-company" size="31" maxlength="99" value="" />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-address1" id="labelshipping-address1" class="text"> <strong>Street Address 1:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_address1" id="shipping-address1" size="31" maxlength="99" value="" />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-address2" id="labelshipping-address2" class="text"> <strong>Street Address 2:</strong> </label>
                        <label for="shipping-city" id="labelshipping-city" class="text"> <strong>City:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_city" id="shipping-city" size="10" maxlength="99" value="" />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-state" id="labelshipping-state" class="text"> <strong>State:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_state" id="shipping-state" size="13" maxlength="99" value=""  />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-zip" id="labelshipping-zip" class="text"> <strong>Zip Code:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_zip" id="shipping-zip" size="10" maxlength="99" value=""  />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-phone" id="labelshipping-phone" class="text"> <strong>Phone:</strong>
                            <input type="text" class="text" name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_phone" id="shipping-phone" size="10" maxlength="99" value=""  />
                        </label>
                        <label for="shipping-country" id="labelshipping-country"> <strong>Country:</strong>
                            <select name="shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_country" id="shipping-country" >
                                <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                                <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                                <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                                <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                                <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
                                <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegowina</option>
                                <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                                <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
                                <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                                <option value="HR">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
                                <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
                                <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
                                <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                                <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
                                <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
                                <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                                <option value="FR">France</option>
                                <option value="FX">France, Metropolitan</option>
                                <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                                <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
                                <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                                <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
                                <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                                <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
                                <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
                                <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                                <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                                <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                                <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                                <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
                                <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
                                <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
                                <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
                                <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                                <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
                                <option value="MT">Malta</option>
                                <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                                <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                                <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                                <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                                <option value="PL">Poland</option>
                                <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                                <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                                <option value="SK">Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option>
                                <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
                                <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
                                <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                                <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                                <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                                <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
                                <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
                                <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
                                <option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option>
                                <option value="VA">Vatican City</option>
                            </select> </label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ys_majorSection">
            <h3>Other Information</h3>
            <h4>Coupon Code</h4>
            <div class="ys_subSection" id="ys_coupon" style="">
                <div class="ys_subSection">
                    <fieldset id="ys_couponFieldset">
                        <label for="gc-redemption-code" id="labelgc-redemption-code"> <strong>If you have a Coupon / Promotional code that can be redeemed from this store, please enter the offer code in the box below.</strong> </label>
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="gcPaymentDS.gcpayment_ROW0_redemptionCode" id="gc-redemption-code" size="20" maxlength="" value="" />
                        <input class="ys_secondary" type="submit" name="eventName.updateGiftCertDataEvent"  value="Apply" />
                        <em><!-- intentionally empty --></em>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4>Email Notification</h4>
            <div class="ys_subSection" id="ys_billingEmail" style="">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="billing-email" id="labelbilling-email" class="text">
                        <strong>Email Address:</strong>
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="miscDS.shopperEmailAddress" id="billing-email" size="40" maxlength="99" value=""  />
                        <input type="hidden" name="miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_ymixval" value="req,email" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_ymixlabel" value="Email Address" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="miscDS.shopperEmailAddress_secname" value="BillingEmail" />
                        <em><!-- intentionally empty --></em> </label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code above I have to confess I stopped after the PHP file. The quick answer is that preg_replace needs 3 arguments not 2 in order to work. First argument is the pattern you are trying to find, second is the replacement and the last one is the text.

And if you are looking to improve your overall code here is some advice:

First of all, checking for $_POST is not the best option, you should check for

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"
```

Then please validate your input, I must confess I never used the $_fields variable, but if it is pre-populated with the elements inside the $_POST array you should consider that  anything can be in there not just what you expect from your form (other people can just use curl to hack that code and add anything inside the database).

You should also use stripslashes in combination with addslashes on your input to provide the minimum level of security. The colon is not your only problem, other things can be in there, things that you do not want.

Lastly you can just use str_replace("string to be replaced","replacement","some text you need string to be replaced on")

Hope this helps

Comment: Turns out by talking with a friend and doing some debugging on the JS, it is not being posted to the PHP file. I think it has to do with the Ajax post that I have set up, so we are going to work on it over the weekend. Thanks for the help though, you have made things easier for when we get the JS side of the code working.